# Apple Game Center Leaderboard data doesn't match

Tags: game-center

I'm successfully posting high scores to apple game center but when I view the game center leaderboard UI the data is odd and doesn't match. I am testing with 5 different game center accounts on 5 different devices, but the "All xxx Players" section of the leader board shows only two or three players per device instead of the expected 5. Other weird behaviour:

1. I see myself and one friend's score in the "Friends" area, but only myself and one other person (not my friend) in the  "All 2 Players" area. Why don't I see my friend?
2. On another device, i correctly see myself and a (different) friend in the "Friends" area, but my friend has a different score (smaller) score when listed in the 'All 3 Players" area below.

I am in sandbox environment, if that matters, but I don't want to wait until prod to find there is something wrong. If it is simply stale data, is there any API call I should be doing to refresh this data?

EDIT: The above was the behaviour seen with Apple's **reportScoreWithCompletionHandler**() api.

Comment: Not sure why this is considered off-topic; I am calling iOS APIs and they are not behaving as expected, so I am looking for experienced developers to suggest alternate API calls (or suggest why I am getting the unexpected behaviour).

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed either. It's an excellent question; well-written and on-topic. (It's a Game Center software development question, and it's tagged "game-center" for goodness' sake. What else do you want?) It's also a problem that I'm struggling with too. @bitcoder: Did you ever figure out why the data was inconsistent between different devices?

Comment: Typical SO BS to close this as OT

Comment: Didn't find a satisfactory answer, although I do get more data eventually (seems like a varying, up to 12+hrs delay). It never seems to get everything, and I have seen a few more cases where I see my friend in the 'friend' area but not in the top scores area. My manager didn't feel it was worth following up though, so moved onto other things. I should have put in that I was using the 'reportScoreWithCompletionHandler' API call though.

Comment: Also agree that this should not have been closed.

Comment: This question is great and clear and perfectly describes the problem. Game Center is reporting STALE data, how do you fix this (since the documented API does not work correctly)... how is that off topic?